# get count of families that have more than 1 child in their record

Tags: mysql, sql

This is the query that I have, but it takes long to finish.

```
SELECT count(*) AS count_all 
FROM families 
WHERE family_status_cat_id = 1374 
      AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM childrens WHERE family_id = families.id) > 1 
      AND unit_id IN (49,33,74,327,329,453,454,469,472,546,547)
```

Is there a way to make it better?

Comment: Yes, "childrens" is not an English word :).

Comment: What indexes do you have on `families` and `childrens`?

Comment: may be IN takes much time

Comment: @Michal have you never heard of double plurals? "peoples" is a real word, plural of "people". It is similar to double past tense: find, found, founded.

Comment: @www.sblog.in that depends on the right indexes. If it's a table scan, it will take a while, if it's an index check, it might not even need to read a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query will probably work fine with the right indexes.  I would suggest the following two:

```
create index families_fsc_unitid on families(family_status_cat_id, unit_id);
create index children_familyid on children(family_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HAVING` clause allows you to filter out rows which do not meet some aggregate condition

```
select
    count(*)
from families
inner join
    (
        SELECT 
            family_id 
        FROM childrens as c
        group by family_id 
        having COUNT(*) > 1 -- more than one child in the family
    ) as MultiChild
    on MultiChild.falily_id = families.id
```

You will, of course, need to add back in the other conditions which I have omitted.